# How to fix Angular error Property 'bankCode' does not exist on type 'User' when trying to bind the property to ng model?

Tags: html, angular, typescript, compiler-errors, ngmodel

I have an application where I'm trying to get the values from mongo db and display it in a table in angular. I created a user class with the values name, password etc but it keeps saying that the property does not exist on type User. It used to work before even though I had the same compilation errors so I ignored it but at times it comes as cannot Get when I try to open the page and other times it works even with the errors. Please help, it's an assignment and I need it to compile properly when I'm submitting it.

[Picture of the Error:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UTCMV.png)

user.ts file

```
export class User {

  constructor( userId: number,
    name: string,
    bankCode:string,
  
    password: string,
    branchCode:string){}
 
  
  }
```

addAccComponent.ts file

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

import {RegisterService} from '../../register.service';
import { User } from 'src/app/user';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-addacc',
  templateUrl: './addacc.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./addacc.component.css']
})
export class AddaccComponent implements OnInit {
 
  user:User= new User(0,"","","",""
  );
   message:any;

constructor(private service: RegisterService) { }

ngOnInit() {
}



public addAccount(){
 let response= this.service.addAcc(this.user);
 response.subscribe((data)=>this.message=data);
 

}

}
```

HTML component

```
<link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" id="bootstrap-css">
<script src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>

        
     
<div style="text-align: center">
    <h1>{{message}}</h1>
</div>

<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <form>
                <fieldset>
                    <legend class="text-center">Valid information is required to register. <span class="req"><small>
                                required *</small></span></legend>

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="Name"><span class="req">* </span> Name: <small>This will be your login user
                                name</small> </label>
                        <input required type="text" [(ngModel)]="user.name" name="name" id="name"
                            class="form-control phone" maxlength="28" placeholder="Enter your fullname..." />
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="Id"><span class="req">* </span> ID: </label>
                        <input class="form-control" type="number" [(ngModel)]="user.userId" name="id" id="number" required
                            placeholder="ID" />
                        <div id="errFirst"></div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="password"><span class="req">* </span> Password : </label>
                        <input class="form-control" type="password" [(ngModel)]="user.password" name="password" id="txt"
                             required />
                        <div id="errLast"></div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="branch code"><span class="req">* </span> Branch Code: </label>
                        <input class="form-control" required type="text" [(ngModel)]="user.branchCode" name="domain"
                            id="email" placeholder="code..." />
                        <div class="status" id="status"></div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="bank code"><span class="req">* </span> Bank Code: </label>
                        <input class="form-control" required type="text" [(ngModel)]="user.bankCode" name="domain"
                            id="email" placeholder="code..." />
                        <div class="status" id="status"></div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <input class="btn btn-success" type="submit" name="submit_reg" value="Add user" (click)="addAccount()">
                    </div>
                </fieldset>
            </form> <!--ends register form -->
            <!-- second for to fiter user-->
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

The class User does not have the properties you try to access. You need to have:

```
export class User {
  public userId: number;
  public name: string;
  public bankCode: string;
  public password: string;
  public branchCode: string;

  constructor(userId: number, name: string, bankCode: string, password: string, branchCode: string) {
    this.userId = userId;
    this.name = name;
    this.bankCode = bankCode;
    this.password = password;
    this.branchCode = branchCode;
  }
}
```

Comment: you can also simply prefix each of the constructor arguments with `public` for the same effect